# SmoothDamp while decreasing scale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I SmoothDamp while decreasing scale? For example, decrease scale from 10 to 1 from `transform.position` to `targetPosition`?

Here's the code:

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothTime = 0.3F;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

void Update() {
    Vector3 targetPosition = target.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interpolate values over time with something like [Mathf.Lerp()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) or [Vector3.Lerp()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) depending on what you're trying to scale.

Both Lerp functions take a start value, an end value and `t`, a number between 0 and 1 that calculates the 'scale' between both start and end values.

`var scale = Mathf.Lerp(10f, 1f, t);`

---

Let's say you wanted to scale the MaxSpeed parameter of your `Vector3.SmoothDamp` operation in a linear fashion between your start and end points.
We'll need to scale the **total distance** down to a `t` value between 0 and 1:

*First, calulate the total distance your SmoothDamp path intends to travel. Store this so it won't be modified.*

```
private float _totalDist;
private Vector3 _targetPosition = Vector3.zero;

private void Start()
{
   _totalDist = Vector3.Distance(_targetPosition, transform.position);
}
```

*Then you can easily get the `t` value as your position changes:*

```
private void Update()
{
   var dist = Vector3.Distance(_targetPosition, transform.position);
   var t = Mathf.Clamp01(dist / _totalDist);
...
```

*Finally you can apply the Lerp value to your SmoothDamp operation:*

```
...
   var speedScale = Mathf.Lerp(10f, 1f, t);
   transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, _targetPosition,
      ref velocity, smoothTime, maxSpeed: speedScale);
}
```

This is merely an example, apply the lerp method do whatever property you wish to scale.